# Why doesn't `scrollbar-gutter: stable` work on the `body` element?

Tags: html, css

According to the [documentation for `scrollbar-gutter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter), if an element has both `scrollbar-gutter: stable` and `overflow: hidden` then the scroll bar gutter should be present.

For some reason, I can't get this to work for the `body` element (tested in Chrome and Firefox). It's working for other elements e.g. `div` in the example below, so why doesn't it work for the `body` element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    }

    div {
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <hr />

    <div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your body overflow is being propagated to the viewport, but the scrollbar-gutter is not.

The [scrollbar-gutter specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-overflow/#scrollbar-gutter-property) says:

> As for the overflow property, when scrollbar-gutter is set on the root element, the user agent must apply it to the viewport instead, and the used value on the root element itself is scrollbar-gutter: auto. However, unlike the overflow property, the user agent must not propagate scrollbar-gutter from the HTML body element.

So to make the scrollbar-gutter appear on the body element, give the root element `overflow:auto` to stop the body's overflow being propagated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <style>
    html {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    }

    div {
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <hr />

    <div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or if you want the scrollbar gutter on the viewport, assign `scrolbar-gutter:stable` to the root element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <style>
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
      scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    }
    body {
      border: 1px solid;
    }

    div {
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <hr />

    <div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```